# Writing "/r/n" to newlines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm reading text blobs from a db and I have to write them to files.

Those strings are like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\r\nconsectetur adipiscing elit,\r\nsed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\r\n\r\nUt enim ad minim veniam,\r\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

and i need to write them like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

is there a simpler way to achieve this than reading char by char and perform a `file.write('\n')` everytime I run into a `\r\n`?

my code:

```
import sqlite3
import codecs  

db = sqlite3.connect('blog.sqlite')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''select filename, filecontent from mytable''')
all_rows = cursor.fetchall()    

for row in all_rows:
    with codecs.open(row[0], 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(row[1])
db.close()
```

`filename` is just a plain string, `filecontent` has accented letters and i want to avoid �s

example data:

```
Mi sono trovato nella condizione di dover fare una join su più campi.  \r\nChe stavano in una colonna sola.  \r\nSeparati da punti e virgola.\r\n\r\nPrima di tentare il suicidio, ho googolato un pò e ho scoperto questo:\r\n\r\n    :::sql\r\n    SELECT *  \r\n    FROM tabella1 LEFT JOIN tabella2 ON tabella2.colonnaA IN (  \r\n        SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(tabella2.colonnaB,'[\\^;]+', 1, level) FROM dual  \r\n        CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(tabella2.colonnaB, '[\\^;]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL  \r\n    );\r\n\r\nForse è una cosa risaputa, ma non la conoscevo...  \r\nSicuramente la riutilizzerò tantissimo.\r\n
```

Comment: Forward slashes have no meaning. Did you mean `\r\n` perhaps?

Comment: Also, if your data contains actual CR/NL pairs, then just writing them to a file directly will Do The Right Thing. Can you please clarify what your data looks like (perhaps showing a `print(repr(data))` sample, so we get to see if these are actual newline bytes or just sequences of characters consisting of (back) slashes and letters).

Comment: Next, if you don't actually have proper line separator characters, the simplest is to just use `str.replace()` to replace the sequence of characters that is meant to be a newline with `\n'`.

Comment: `str.replace("\r\n", "\n")`

Comment: @MartijnPieters I misstyped, you're right. I edited the question and I added also example data. That's the data as is on the db

Comment: So what issues did you have when you wrote that to a file? On Python 3 `\r\n` is **automatically translated** to your platform default. Use the `newline` option of `open()` to alter how they are handled. What is your actual problem, what did not work and what should have happened instead?

Comment: edited the question again: i added actual-ish code and actual data. i don't get it why `\r\n` isn't automatically translated (as i also expected), i think maybe it could be a encoding problem

Comment: i figured out: i had to do `str.replace(r'\r\n', '\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: I had to do `str.replace(r'\r\n', '\n')` to search raw strings